# Parse log4j error stream into JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, log4j

I'm using the following shell command (spawned by my node.js program) to parse the errors out of a log4j log file:

`tail -F -n +0 LOGFILE.log | grep 'ERROR\|^[[:space:]]*at' --before-context=2`

This picks up all lines with 'ERROR' in them, and all stack traces, with 2 preceding lines for context.

The errors look like the following:

```
2014-10-15 01:55:12,402 [fault (self-tuning)'] [TABTHREAD7] [App:01.01.01] (Classinfo.Action)     ERROR stageinfo.company.com|11.222.33.444 userName - Error message telling us what went wrong
From: (unknown)
at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:21)
at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:22)
at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:23)
at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:24)
at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:25)
```

I want to take this stream of data and parse it so that I end up with a JSON Object like the following:

```
JSONErrorObject = 
{
"Date" : "2014-10-15",
"Timestamp" : "01:55:12,402",
"Error" : "Error message telling us what went wrong",
"Stack Trace" : "at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:21)
   at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:22)
   at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:23)
   at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:24)
   at ExceptionThrower.main(ExceptionThrower.java:25)"
};
```

I'm reading the stdout (stream) of the grep command and want to parse the incoming lines so that they get converted to the above JSON format. From whatever I've read, it seems like I should write a processor/parser in my node program which can string.match(regex) and pull these chunks under the properties that I require, using a concept similar to the one below:

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = "Shant Want";
var myArray = str.match(re);
var JSONStr = {
    "First name" : myArray[1],
    "Last name" : myArray[2]
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONStr));

// Output is {"First name":"Shant","Last name":"Want"}
```

The regex I'm using is:

```
/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) (\[(.*)\]) \((.*)\)\s+([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) - (.*)$/g
```

My node code is below (writing the data to a file for now just to test):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var net = require('fs');

var parseSh = spawn('sh', [ 'errorParser.sh' ]); //errorParser.sh has the one line parser - tail -F -n +0 LOGFILE.log | grep 'ERROR\|^[[:space:]]*at' --before-context=2
console.log("start tailing");

parseSh.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    var str = data.toString();
    var re = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) (\[(.*)\]) \((.*)\)\s+([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) - (.*)$/g;
    var myArray = str.match(re);
    fs.appendFile('myArray.txt', myArray, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("It's saved!");
    });
});
```

This works alright when the file has one single line, and it populates myArray with the required values. However, when dealing with a stream, it fails spectacularly. It gives me a bunch of random "nullnullnullnullnullnullnull" values in between. **How can I achieve this same result when working with streams?** I'm trying to stream huge log files (> 1gb).

**UPDATE**

I'm just using the "readline" module (http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) and reading one line at a time from the intermediate file. Non-ideal from a performance standpoint, but it's the best I have for now. The code below seems to work just fine.

```
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        console.log(line);
        var str = line.toString();
        var re = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) (.*ERROR) (.*) - (.*)/;

    if(str.search(re) != -1){

        var myArray = str.match(re);
        var JSONErr = {
                "Date": myArray[1],
                "Time": myArray[2],
                "Error": myArray[5]
            };
            client.write(JSON.stringify(JSONErr));
         }
});
```

Comment: You've got a lot of questions here. For instance, >>"How can I parse the incoming stream and store as JSON?" It makes sense to specify what you have tried so far and which problems you encounter. Otherwise the questions seems to be too vague. (there are probably thousands of ways to achieve the desired result, so only outlining your specific problem can allow helping you)

Comment: @Isantipov You're right - let's stick to that question. "How can I parse the incoming stream and store as JSON". So far, I've tried something like the following:

    `var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
     var str = "Shant Want";
     var myArray = str.match(re);
     var JSONStr = {
         "First name" : myArray[1],
         "Last name" : myArray[2]
     };
     console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONStr));
     // Output is {"First name":"Shant","Last name":"Want"}`

The regex I'm using is `/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) (\[(.*)\]) \((.*)\) \s ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) - (.*)$/`

Comment: Here's the code when trying to make it work with streams. I get a weird output in the file. [Sorry, I'm struggling to show newlines in code when entering comments]

`parseSh.stdout.on("data", function (data) {

    var str = data.toString();
    var re = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) (\[(.*)\]) \((.*)\)\s+([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) - (.*)$/g;
    var myArray = str.match(re);
    fs.appendFile('myArray.txt', myArray, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("It's saved!");
    });
   client.write(data);
});`

Comment: you'd better embed the code into the question text, so node.js experts can see it and help you. Also, outline what the problem is (e.g. you get an error or just the result you receive does not match what you think it should be - then specify, what the expected vs actual difference is)

Comment: OK, made the changes, thanks!

Comment: I guess it's safe to assume that there's no way to do this without reading the intermediate file line-by-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "readline" module (http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html), read one line at a time from the intermediate file. Non-ideal from a performance standpoint, but it's the best bet for now. The code below seems to work just fine:

```
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log(line);
    var str = line.toString();
    var re = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}) (.*ERROR) (.*) - (.*)/;

if(str.search(re) != -1){

    var myArray = str.match(re);
    var JSONErr = {
            "Date": myArray[1],
            "Time": myArray[2],
            "Error": myArray[5]
        };
        client.write(JSON.stringify(JSONErr));
     }
```

});